# Maclaurin series for $e^z /\cos z$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to find the Maclaurin series for the function

$$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{\cos z}.$$

Right away I can tell that the radius of convergence will be $\pi/2$, since it's the distance to the nearest singularity (not sure if this explanation is rigorous enough, but I can't think of anything else). Calculating the coefficients as n'th derivatives at $0$ strikes me as fruitless here, so I'm guessing I have to resort to tricks. Of course I could just divide the series formally but that doesn't get me an explicit formula for the coefficient $a_n$.

I tried rewriting the cosine as an exponential, but that too produces nothing of interest. I'm looking for a hint to get me started.

Comment: The explanation of the convergence radius is rigorous :) Usually when you compute first 4 or 5 coefficients by derivatives, you get the idea as what the formula for them is and then proving it works is usually quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

$$
\expo{z} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{z^{k} \over k!}
\quad
\left\vert%
\begin{array}{rcl}
\qquad\sec\pars{z} & = & \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\verts{E_{2k}} \over \pars{2k}!}z^{2k}
\\
\verts{z} & < & {\pi \over 2}
\\[2mm]
&&E_{\nu}\ \mbox{is an}\ {\it\mbox{Euler Number}}.
\end{array}\right.
$$

\begin{align}
&\vphantom{\Huge A^{A}}
\\
{\expo{z} \over \cos\pars{z}}
&=
\expo{z}\sec\pars{z}
=
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{k' = 0}^{\infty}{z^{k} \over k!}\,
{\verts{E_{2k'}} \over \pars{2k'}!}z^{2k'}
=
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{k' = 0}^{\infty}{z^{k} \over k!}\,
{\verts{E_{2k'}} \over \pars{2k'}!}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{n - k}\,\delta_{n,k + 2k'}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{n}
\sum_{k' = 0 \atop {\vphantom{\LARGE A}n - 2k' \geq 0}}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{n - 2k'}!}\,
{\verts{E_{2k'}} \over \pars{2k'}!}
\end{align}

> $${\large%
> {\expo{z} \over \cos\pars{z}}
> =
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}A_{n}\,z^{n}\,,
> \qquad\qquad
> A_{n}
> \equiv
> \sum_{k = 0}^{\floor{n/2} \atop }
> {\verts{E_{2k}} \over \pars{2k}!\pars{n - 2k}!}}
> $$

Comment: Perhaps some words or explanations would help this jumble of equations make sense...

Comment: What are $E_k$ ?

Comment: @DepeHb $\large E_{2k}$ is an Euler Number. $\large\left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor$ is the $\it floor$ function.

Comment: I do not understand the usage of the delta function here and the changes to the indicies.

Comment: @DepeHb It's a multiplication of series. The delta makes easier to join the powers of $\large z$ in an only one $\large z^{n}$. In addition, we can see immediately what are the range of the indexes. At the end ( gray box ) we don't need any more $\large k'$. So, we use $\large k$ for economic of notation. The use of the delta avoids to make drawings in the $\large kk'$ plane just to figure out what are the limits. Maybe, in this example it is unnecessary. It illustrates a useful "technique" for more complicated cases. Indeed, I'm very bad when I draw any thing.

Comment: The delta is a really neat trick but I can't find any information about its usage for series multiplication on the internet, and it's still not entirely clear for me how it was used here. In particular, I find the equality with $\sum z^n \sum_{n-2k'\ge 0, k'=0} ...$ problematic .

Comment: Alright, I think I get it. Thanks for showing me this method!

Comment: @DepeHb $\large n - 2k' \geq 0$ sets the upper limit of $\large k'$ and it's equivalent to $\large k' \leq n/2$. Since $\large k'$ is an integer, $\large k' \leq \left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor$.