# Taylor expansion of $e^z /\cos z$ around z=0

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to find the Taylor series for the function $$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{\cos z}$$

I found this post ([Maclaurin series for $e^z /\cos z$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533312/maclaurin-series-for-ez-cos-z)) but the answer doesn't do it for me. I know the radius of convergence will be $z<π/2$. I am looking for a simpler trick to find the series without having to resort to Euler Numbers and Delta functions. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you want a closed form for all the coefficients, or just the first few terms?

Comment: @RobertIsrael A closed form for infinite terms $0\leq n<\infty$

Comment: It's very unlikely that there is one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How about the first few terms then? Have any tips?

Comment: $\cos(z) = 1 - z^2/2! + z^4/4! + \ldots$, $e^z = 1 + z + z^2/2! + z^3/3! + z^4/4! + \ldots$, and do "[long division](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408s/AS/LM11-10-5.html)".